# How to catch an exception raised from a called function?

Tags: python-3.x, try-catch

I have a function that raises an exception if a file exists:

```
def save_template(rendered_template, target_path, file_name):
    fl = os.path.join(target_path, file_name)
    if os.path.exists(fl):
        raise Exception
    with open(fl, "w") as f:
        f.write(rendered_template)
```

I have another function that calls `save_template`.

```
def build_controller():
    # ... some other code
    try:
        save_template(rendered, path, file_name)

    except:
        echo(f"{path}/{file_name} already exists. Doing nothing.", "yellow")
```

The `try-except` statement in `build_controller` is not catching the exception. The exception is being raised from `save_template`.

I've also tested with this:

```
def save_template(rendered_template, target_path, file_name):
    raise Exception
```

And this:

```
def save_template(rendered_template, target_path, file_name):
    return Exception
```

With the same result.

How do I catch errors from `save_template` and run my `echo` command if there's an error?

Comment: Are you sure that the exception is being thrown?

Comment: Yes. I can edit `save_template` to immediately return or raise the Exception with the same result.

Comment: If the exception isn't being thrown, doesn't that mean `os.path.exists(fl)`  is returning `False`?

Comment: I edited the question for clarity on this point.